# How do I close separate sessions using node.js express-session?

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am using express-session module for session handling in my express.js app

My express.js application creates session for user and admin privileges.

I have **req.session.user** & **req.session.admin**

The problem I have is I don't know how to close 1 session and not the other.

You can close a session with this command: **req.session.destroy()**

But that destroys both sessions. I tried using **req.session.user.destroy()** with no luck. It is not a valid command.

So how can I destroy 1 session and not the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a normal configuration, there is only one session object for each browser per site.  That session object can have multiple properties, but there is only one session so you don't destroy a session just to remove a property.  Further, the session is just a plain Javascript object so you can add/remove properties from it.

Since you're talking about "separate sessions", it's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish.  You can remove individual properties from the session with the `delete` operator as in:

```
delete req.session.admin;
```

This will remove the `.admin` property from the session object, but leave the session itself and other properties on it intact.

Answer (score 0):

may be help you -> delete req.session.user

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follows to unset session property:

```
delete req.session.username;
//OR
req.session.username=null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
req.session.user = "";
req.session.admin = "";
req.session.destroy((err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
            res.redirect('/[url]'); // replace [url] with your desired route
        }
});
```

Hope this helps.